# Password Protected View Doesn't Work with Custom Template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, password-protection

I'm trying to set up a password protection for a static custom Wordpress template page. I set the password in a dashboard and included this code in my template file:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: QN PDF */
get_header();
?>
<?php
global $post;

if (!post_password_required($post)) {

    echo get_the_password_form();
    include('inc/section/pdf.php');
} else {
     echo get_the_password_form();
}

?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

In result a password form shows up at the top, but the content is not hidden and still loads up. What is the right way to hide the content with the password?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are basically saying... if there is *no* password required, then show the password form.

Instead you should be displaying your content here – the_content(). Since you are echo'ing the password form, regardless of whether the post is password-protected or not, you are seeing it displayed along with the included PDF and thinking it is showing when locked.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: QN PDF */
get_header();
?>
<?php
global $post;

if (!post_password_required($post)) { // if there is no password required

    // display the content
    the_content();
    include('inc/section/pdf.php');

} else {

    //display the password form 
    echo get_the_password_form();
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to help people understand what was the issue and what is the fix. Code only answers are hyroglyphs to many readers.